# Если в конструкторе класса открывается файл, обязательно ли его закрывать?

Tags: java

Если в конструкторе класса открывается файл, обязательно ли его закрывать?

Comment: да, нужно закрывать. Думаете придет маленький гномик и закроет его за вас?

Comment: Открытие файла в конструкторе является очень плохой практикой. Вы не сможете сконструировать объект без открытия файла, а уж про исключения в конструкторе я вообще молчу

Comment: @Etki подскажите, что тогда нужно передать в такой ситуации: конструктору нужен `.xml` и `.dtd` файлы, сначала он проверяет валидность `.xml` с помощью `Validator`, а потом читает данные, если всё ок с помощью `SAXParser`. Если передавать два объекта типа `File`, то в метод `validate()` они не передаются, т.к. он требует `Source`, а если передавать `Source` - то не `parse()` не принимает... :(

Comment: я зайду ортогонально: зачем у вас конструктор выполняет все те вещи, для которых не предназначен?

Comment: @Etki ну идея такая: класс может быть создан только с помощью `.xml` файла, поэтому у него 1 конструктор

Comment: Одно из другого не следует (как и не следует, что в конструкторе должна быть запрятана тонна логики)

Comment: @Etki тогда как сделать? если где-то извне считать данные из файла, а потом передавать эти данные в конструктор, то их потенциально можно получить и из другого места, не только `.xml` файла

Comment: и в чем здесь проблема? если потенциальный злоумышленник настолько хорош, что живьем вклеился в ваше приложение, что ему мешает вообще переписать весь байт-код? и почему ваша фабрика (или что это еще) работает с xml-файлами, если на самом деле ей нужна схема и только схема для создания чего-то там?

Comment: @Etki нужна и схема и сам файл, чтобы проверить, правильная ли там информация. Я читаю, а не записываю

Comment: @user232346 используйте для создания паттерн Builder https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: нет, проверить корректность файла - задача того, кто читает схему. в фабрику должна поступать уже валидная схема.

Comment: @Etki ясно, тогда буду только файл передавать

Comment: @Etki а если я указываю dtd схему прямо в xml документе, мне вообще имеет смысл её в программе проверять?

Comment: @Etki т.е. проверять xml документ на соответствие этой схеме

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если под файлом подразумевается поток и если Вы не используете `try-with-resources` , то да, его нужно обязательно закрывать (и тут совсем неважно, где Вы открываете поток: в методе, в конструкторе или еще где-нибудь).